# create array from mysql and store in session

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table like this:

```
id | name | value
------------------
1  | logo      | blahblahblah.png
2  | namestore | blah store
3  | ip        | 0.0.0.0
```

My question is how can I fetch that table using mysql, then create a php call, for example :

```
$store->logo (i will get blahblahblah.png)
$store->namestore ( i will get blah store)
```

Can anyone help me? I'm just getting confused about how to do this

Comment: What did you tried so far.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @LearneR, please don't point new PHP users to the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: i already found it guys.. thanks for the attention.. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use that



 $sql = "select * from your_table_name;";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $conn)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
             echo 'error !';
    }

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       //your fetch results are stored in $arr array. you can get values with $arr['column_name']
    }
```

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch your example code to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).  That said, this answer is about as helpful as a punch to the nose.  Could you perhaps explain how you think this will help solve the OP's problem?